# How should I add a JavaScript onclick event to link to a lower folder?

Tags: javascript, razor, onclick

I have a menu element where I link to certain other pages in a pretty standard way via an unordered list. Such as:

```
<li><a href="@Href("~/Admin/Staff/")">Staff</a></li>
```

Obviously, that gives me a link to the appropriate page of my site that is activated when the user clicks the text 'Staff'.
I want to enable the user to click anywhere in the li element to activate the link, so a simple JavaScript onclick event seemed best. I tried:

```
<li onclick="location.href='~/Admin/Staff/'"><a href="@Href("~/Admin/Staff/")">Staff</a></li>
```

but all that did was append '/Admin/Staff/' to whatever the current URL was. I've tried replacing the ~ with . and .. but got similarly wrong results. I've tried replacing location.href= with location.hostname+ and still got nowhere.

It seems to me that this use is perfectly fine when navigating to another file within the same or a lower hierarchy folder, but JavaScript seems not to like the "find the root folder" mechanism used by HTML. Does anyone here have a nice cross-browser solution for this? I'd prefer a non-jQuery solution so as not to have to import the whole jQuery library just for a very simple task like this.

Comment: You CaNt OpEn the FOLDER. :P

Comment: `onclick="location.href += '/Admin/Staff/'`

Comment: `onclick='location.href=@Href("~/Admin/Staff/")'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `Href()` every time. `Href` resolves the ~/ into the actual virtual directory or root path of your application.

```
<li onclick="location.href='@Href("~/Admin/Staff/")'">
    <a href="@Href("~/Admin/Staff/")">Staff</a>
</li>
```

Or if you want to specify and evaluate it only once:

```
@{
    var staffPath = Href("~/Admin/Staff/");
}

<li onclick="location.href='@(staffPath)'">
    <a href="@(staffPath)">Staff</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a speedy answer and concise explanation.